# Remove alphabet and special case. Display only number of specific line text

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Version=14.0.1400.2150

I have this .ini file which contains version number. I want to remove "Version" and "=" text, display it on cmd without that text just 14.0.1400.2150

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `for` loop and use `find` to find the specific field, then split the text by `=` and use the second token (text after `=`)

You just need to replace `test.ini` with your actual file name.

From `cmd`

```
for /f "tokens=2delims==" %a in ('type test.ini ^| find /i "Version="') do echo %a
```

and from `batch-file`

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2delims==" %%a in ('type test.ini ^| find /i "Version="') do echo %%a
```